# Facing problems redirecting user using django post_save signal

Tags: python, django

When ever a user creates a new chat thread, i want to automatically  redirect them to the thread. But facing problems

example  my models

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()
    creator=models.ForeignKey(User)
class Chat(models.Model):
    thread=models.ForeignKey(Thread)
    message=models.TextField()
```

User creates a thread , and has to be redirected to the created thread('app:chat',pk) displaying the Chatform  and thread name.

I tried using django post_save signal to redirect the user after creating a thread

```
def redirect_user(sender,instance,**kwargs)
    pk=instance.id
    url=('app:chat',pk)
    post_save.connect(redirect_user,sender=Thread)
```

Well this is not working. Please help with a good approach to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing that in your view where your form is rendered afaic. If the form is valid then model instance's id should be accessible by the form instance and you may call `return redirect("chat", args=(new_id,))` where "chat" is reversed name.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Django's generic class based views you can quite easily get this functionality

You should use a [`CreateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) for this and then override the `get_success_url` method to redirect the user. [Classy class based views](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/) is a great website for exploring all options for the generic views

```
class ThreadCreateView(CreateView):

    model = Thread

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('app:chat', args=[self.object.pk])
```